# Adding elements of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices as follows:

```
loweredge 
       [,1]  [,2] [,3]
  [1,] -32.5 87.5 207.5

SectorAzimuth
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
 [1,]  10.83 21.66 32.5 43.33 54.16  65
```

I wish to add all 6 values in SectorAzimuth to the first value of loweredge, then add all 6 values in SectorAzimuth to the second value of loweredge and similarly the same 6 values of SectorAzimuth to the 3rd value of loweredge.

Can anyone give me some pointers please?

Comment: I know that I can add the following loweredge[1,1] + SectorAzimuth, is it a case of looping for the dimensions of loweredge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
loweredge <- matrix(c(-32.5, 87.5, 207.5), nrow = 1)
SectorAzimuth <- matrix(c(10.83, 21.66, 32.5, 43.33, 54.16,  65), nrow = 1)

apply(loweredge, MARGIN = 2, FUN = `+`, y = SectorAzimuth)
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
[1,] -21.67  98.33 218.33
[2,] -10.84 109.16 229.16
[3,]   0.00 120.00 240.00
[4,]  10.83 130.83 250.83
[5,]  21.66 141.66 261.66
[6,]  32.50 152.50 272.50
```

Comment: Or `outer(c(SectorAzimuth), c(loweredge), \`+\`)`

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, much appreciated.